# Как организовать Android(C#)+WEB(ModX)

Tags: android

Раньше писал только локальные программы на ПК для решения рабочих задач. Но сейчас поставил себе задачу сделать приложение и вэб интерфейс, плюс оповещения и прочее (некоторые алгоритмы должны запускаться и выполняться на стороне сервера или где-то ещё без участия пользователя). Направление новое, спросить неукого. Как правильно организовать это всё? Если хостинг, тогда он не будет решать ничего без пользователя, если выделенный сервер, то надо ли ставить отдельную СУБД или с базы сайта это всё... Тогда сайт должен стучаться в эту СУБД... Не понимаю... Арендавать выделенный сервер, потратить неделю чтобы разобраться как он арендуется и месяц пыхтеть как это сделать - перспектива так-себе... Может книга какая есть по этой теме.

Comment: Можете в локальной сети все организовать.
Веб-приложение запущенное на вашем рабочей машине будет доступно в сети(если мобильное приложение подключено к тому же WI-FI роутеру, что и рабочая машина).
В роутере по мак-адресу можете настроить выдачу определенных IP-шников конкретным машинам, чтобы они не выдавались рандомно и можно было по одному и тому-же IP всегда обращаться

Comment: А когда тестите в эмуляторе вообще можете на 127.0.0.1 обращаться

Comment: про выделенный сервер и СУБД с пользователем вообще не понял что вы имеете в виду и что вас смущает.

Comment: Чтобы потыкать достаточно просто все это дело развернуть в одной локальной сети. И играйтесь сколько хотите.

Comment: На хостинге пока разворачиваю базовую часть. Разберусь с азами, а там глядишь и решение само придёт... Думаю буду делать как обычно в моей практике: начну писать, а там увидим.